Elastic Search redirects to configurable product
After i enter a term in search bar, for some search strings, it redirects to configurable product page. The search page loads for a few seconds and is immediately redirected to configurable product page. I have checked in code,does not have any redirects. Any ideas would be a huge help. Thanks in advance.

did you run the indexer?

yes..indexer runs fine. still getting redirected.
